# Fire Adobe DTM Page Load Rule Based On Class Or ID Value

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics

I'm trying to fire a page load rule in Adobe DTM based on class or ID value. For example, I have multiple dropdown lists, after the member selects all values from the DDL, a lable with all values selected will display on the page with whatever the user selected from the DDL. How can I fire the rule based on that label class or ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event based rule and under conditions, select `enters viewport`. This will trigger the event when your class or id is shown. You could also fire it on the `change` event so that when ever a value is selected an event will fire, you can even choose specific values that must be selected to trigger your rule.